# What is the order of resolution of abilities during the damage step?

Tags: final-fantasy-tcg

I was curious how abilities resolve during damage calculation. I was playing a game last night where Lightning attacked and wasn't blocked. She has an ability that lets her dull a forward. The damage step caused an ex burst that gave a forward more attack power.

The question really is when do abilities like lightnings resolve, before damage? After damage? Or after or before the EX burst?

Answer (score 1):

The official English rule states: [Official reference guide](https://fftcg.cdn.sqexeu.com/files/downloadables/fftcgrulesheet-en.pdf)

> When defending player receives damage and reveals their damage card, if the card is marked with an EX icon in the top right corner, the player triggers the card's EX Burst and may immediately apply the effects of the card. ...

Therefore here it goes:

1. Lightning is not blocked and produce damage.
2. The Ex Burst is triggered.
3. Then Lightning ability is triggered dulling a forward.

Note that you can't counter Ex Burst. However, auto ability or field ability can be countered.

Answer (score -1):

When Lightning damages your opponent, choose 1 dull it,
When you damage an opponent remove the top card and put it into the damage zone.

Just using this as reference, in MTG if you deal lethal damage to a player with a monster that has life link, they die before you gain life (only matters in multi player) So with this in mind, id say the top card EX goes off first since 1(MTG reference) and 2 (EX burst cannot be interrupted)

Comment: I don't know anything about Final Fantasy, but I think your MtG reference is false - lifelink health is gained immediately ("damage dealt by a source with lifelink _also causes_ that source's controller to gain that much life"), while eliminating the player happens when state-based actions are checked.